# Azure Pipelines "PowerShell on target Machines" Release Task that starts a Selenium Grid Hub, blocks the pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, selenium-grid

I have this `hub.ps1`:

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow javaw -ArgumentList '-jar', 'E:\selenium_grid\selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-3.jar', 'hub'
```

And this task in my pipeline:

[image]

When the task runs during pipeline execution, the grid starts normally:
[image]

but the pipeline task never ends, as if I ran
`java -jar E:\selenium_grid\selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-3.jar hub` in my terminal
and I then I had to hit Control-C to regain terminal control.

I was hoping that `Start-Process` and `javaw` instead of `java` would solve it, but it is not. What is making the task block? Is there something I can do from my PowerShell Script?

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments are not syntax correctly:

`Start-Process javaw -ArgumentList "'-jar', 'E:\selenium_grid\selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-3.jar', 'hub'" -NoNewWindow`

Comment: I thought this worked, but I'm getting this error now: `Error: Could not find or load main class '-jar',`

Comment: It has to be like this `Start-Process javaw -ArgumentList "-jar E:\selenium_grid\selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-3.jar hub" -NoNewWindow` but now it is the same as mine and so it still blocks